# User Account Control on OK Button

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, uac

I have researched over the internet about the UAC functionality on the form OK button but couldn't get the information. All of the information related to implementing the UAC is they relaunch the application with the administrative privileges.

My requirement is to make the application in which when user click on OK button with Shield Icon on it, user will be able to save some information in the windows Registry through elevate the user privilege but I don't want to relaunch the application with administrator rights.

Comment: "I don't want to relaunch the application with administrator rights." Tough. The process token is assigned once when the process starts. So you need a minimum of two processes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You need two processes, but rather than relaunching the same process you can start another one entirely.

Comment: @Servy Yes you can do that. I read the quote from the question meaning, "I don't want to launch another process".

Answer (score 7):

Relaunching the application (or launching a helper application) is what you do. It is the requesting of elevated privileges while launching an application that causes the UAC confirmation screen to appear. The purpose of showing the shield icon is to let the user know that confirmation screen is coming up, basically.

You don't have to just relaunch your application. If your application allows multiple instances, you can launch a second copy with command-line parameters indicating the registry change to make. Or you can have a helper application that does admin things, and launch that as needed. A helper application doesn't need to create or show a window; it can be an entirely background operation.

Answer (score -1):

May be you should add an application manifest and require administrator rights:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

**Edit**

It may not be the best solution here, because the entire application is running under elevated privileges and that can be a security vulnerability.

Comment: The problem there is that you run the entire application with elevated privileges when it needs it conditionally and rarely.  That's a security vulnerability waiting to happen.

Comment: In his question its not clear if he want to run the entire application with elevated privileges or not! Surly every application should use least privileges, but thats not always possible!

Comment: Sure it's possible, just look at the other answer.  The solution is to start a second, background, process that performs the few operations that need elevated privileges.

Comment: Yes I read the second answer, this is a solution. But when the button is used often, than it is really be a performance hit to launch the helper application again and again..

Comment: If it's done that often then you can keep the second process alive and pass commands to it through inter process communication, however it doesn't seem like this is done often enough to warrant that.  Starting a new process even every few seconds isn't really a problem; you'd need to be starting quite a few per second for it to really be "bad".